# Why the size of text created by font of systemFontOfSize and SFPro-Regular aren't equal in iOS13?

Tags: ios, uifont

After I learned the system default font in iOS13 is `SF Pro` according to [apple's development guidance](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/).

I wandering `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]` might can be replayced by `[UIFont fontWithName:@"SFPro-Regular" size:18]`

But I find the size of text with these two kind font is different:

- `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]`: {462.1025390625, 21.48046875}
- `[UIFont fontWithName:@"SFPro-Regular" size:18]`: {459.7998046875, 21.48046875}

Size calculated by `boundingRectWithSize` like this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:content attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
CGRect rect = [attrStr boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
```

Then I tried other fonts like `SF Mono`, `New York`, `SanFrancisco`, all results are different with `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]`

So, the question is:

1. which font is system default really?
2. if `SF Pro` is system default font trully, why the size is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have always been - and likely always will be - slight differences between iOS versions.

Using this code, for example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let v = UILabel()
    v.text = "test"
    view.addSubview(v)
    v.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    v.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 200, height: 60)

}
```

I run it on iOS `12.1` and `iOS 13.3` (different physical devices) and then use `Debug View Hierarchy` to inspect the UI elements, I find out:

- iOS 12: `.SFUIText 18.00pt`
- iOS 13: `.SFUI-Regular 18.00pt`

If you ***really*** need pixel-precision, you almost certainly need to use a custom font for **every** UI element.

I'm not saying "don't use the SF fonts from Apple" ... I'm just saying don't try to mix-and-match `systemFontOfSize` with loading an app-included `fontWithName`.